# Callback action is not firing for columnsToggle button

Tags: javascript, datatables

In the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asanchez4096/urd5gquc/) the action function does not fire whenever a button to select a column in the column visibility button is selected. Below is the code that I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'B',
    "buttons": [
                {
                    extend: 'colvis',
                    postfixButtons: ['colvisRestore'],
                    buttons : [{
                        extend: 'columnsToggle',
                        action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                            alert('Activated!');
                            console.log("Activated!");
                        },
                    }],
                }
            ],
    }
);} );
```

I would really appreciate your help on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

Button [`columnsToggle`](https://datatables.net/reference/button/columnsToggle) doesn't have `action` option as opposed to [`colvis`](https://datatables.net/reference/button/colvis) button.

> **SOLUTION**

Handle [`column-visibility`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/column-visibility) event which is fired when the visibility of a column changes.

```
$('#example').on('column-visibility.dt', function(e, settings, column, state ){
   console.log('Column:', column, "State:", state);    
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urd5gquc/2/) for code and demonstration.