# Checkbox for each button to select a column in Datatables 1.10 without ColVis

Tags: javascript, datatables

As ColVis is deprecated in Datatables 1.10, I am looking for a way to add a checkbox to each button to select a column in the table in the same way it is done in this [example](https://datatables.net/extensions/colvis/) that uses ColVis.

In the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asanchez4096/urd5gquc/) is what I have done so far. Below is the code that I am using.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'B',
    "buttons": [
                {
                    extend: 'colvis',
                    postfixButtons: [
                        {
                            extend: 'colvisRestore',
                            text: 'Restore'
                        }
                    ],
                    buttons : [{
                        extend: 'columnsToggle',
                    }],
                }
            ],
    }
); } );
```

I would really appreciate your share of expertise on this one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

Checkboxes has been replaced by inset/outset styles. However you can simulate a checkbox using CSS, see the rules below:

```css
.dt-button-collection a.buttons-columnVisibility:before,
.dt-button-collection a.buttons-columnVisibility.active span:before {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:1.2em;
    left:0;
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.dt-button-collection a.buttons-columnVisibility:before {
    content:' ';
    margin-top:-6px;
    margin-left:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:3px;
}

.dt-button-collection a.buttons-columnVisibility.active span:before {
    content:'\2714';
    margin-top:-11px;
    margin-left:12px;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #DDD, -1px -1px #DDD, 1px -1px #DDD, -1px 1px #DDD;
}

.dt-button-collection a.buttons-columnVisibility span {
    margin-left:20px;    
}
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urd5gquc/3/) for code and demonstration.

#### NOTES

See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32667503/3549014) to your question explaining why `action` will not work for `columnsToggle` button.

Comment: Thanks, I did see your answer to my previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662750/callback-action-is-not-firing-for-columnstoggle-button/32667503#32667503) in which you explain why `action` will not work for `columnsToggle`. I edited the code above and the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asanchez4096/urd5gquc/) that I refer to in my question to reflect the fact that the `action` function will not work for `columnsToggle`.

Comment: You saved my day dude. Excellent solution. this one works angular data tables too

Comment: Note that `a.buttons-columnVisibility` may be too specific: if you're rendering buttons as `<button>` or altering the class on rendered buttons, the selectors will miss. So, double check the DOM selected in the CSS matches your actual DOM. In my case, I needed to replace `a.buttons-columnVisibility` or `.buttons.columnVisibility`.

Comment: @bishop: I saw your comment after checking everything! Thanks!

Comment: I cant see checkbox using above code. I want button with checkbox. Any Help?

Comment: Thanks @bishop. I couldn't have realized the class was being applied on button instead of a tag in my case. Almost gave up before seeing your comment.

Answer (score 4):

I built upon @gyrocode-com's answer to make it look less "button-y" and more like a **simple list of checkboxes**, as well as to support newer versions of DataTables and Buttons because they now generate the colvis buttons using `<button>` HTML tag and not `<a>`.

```js
buttons: ['colvis']
```

[image: Column selection as a simple checkbox list]

### CSS

```css
.dt-button-collection .dt-button.buttons-columnVisibility {
    background: none !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: none !important;
    padding: 0.25em 1em !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    text-align: left !important;
}
.dt-button-collection .buttons-columnVisibility:before,
.dt-button-collection .buttons-columnVisibility.active span:before {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:1.2em;
    left:0;
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.dt-button-collection .buttons-columnVisibility:before {
    content:' ';
    margin-top:-8px;
    margin-left:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:3px;
}
.dt-button-collection .buttons-columnVisibility.active span:before {
    font-family: 'Arial' !important;
    content:'\2714';
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff, -1px -1px #fff, 1px -1px #fff, -1px 1px #fff;
}
.dt-button-collection .buttons-columnVisibility span {
    margin-left:17px;    
}
```

This also works well with the **multi-column colvis templates** like the `two-column` and `fixed two-column` for example.

```js
buttons: [{
     extend: 'colvis',
     collectionLayout: 'two-column'
  }]
```

[image]

### DEMO

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ct72ne16/1/) for a live demo.

Answer (score 0):

Vouch the answer by @Jiveman back in Aug 13,2020. Its still works well for Button version 2.3.6.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34075629)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).