# CSS ::before property not showing in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using Datatbale 1.10.10

In the Buttons Colvis I have set it to Multicolumn Layout.

I have added this CSS to get the checkbox in the buttons. But it doesn't show on the second column in Chrome, but does get displayed in the Firefox.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32701608/4017803

Here is the CSS code snippet

```
.dt-button-collection a.buttons-columnVisibility:before,
.dt-button-collection a.buttons-columnVisibility.active span:before {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:1.2em;
    left:0;
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.dt-button-collection a.buttons-columnVisibility:before {
    content:' ';
    margin-top:-6px;
    margin-left:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:3px;
}

.dt-button-collection a.buttons-columnVisibility.active span:before {
    content:'\2714';
    margin-top:-11px;
    margin-left:12px;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #DDD, -1px -1px #DDD, 1px -1px #DDD, -1px 1px #DDD;
}

.dt-button-collection a.buttons-columnVisibility span {
    margin-left:20px;    
}
```

Check box works with single column.

So I have converted single column to look like multi-column.
buttons container width double than the buttons width and float left to the buttons.

But this is just a temporary solution. But I would like to know how to fix the multicolumn layout in Chrome.

Comment: Using a single colon for pseudo-elements is a legacy standard for CSS1 and 2. In CSS3, a double colon is expected. There might be a slight  difference in the implementation of the CSS specification between firefox and chrome. Have you tried using `::before` in your CSS rules rather than `:before`?

Comment: same behavior even after ::before