# datatable show/hide columns with checkbox

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, datatables

I have a code in codeigniter, and i am using a data-table, now i want to make a show/hide columns with a checkbox above to let the columns hide or maybe shown. I will populate my data from my database in my controller with these code :

```
public function dataTable_report($date) {
        $user = array('user_id' => $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['user_id']);
        $myreport = $this->Adminreport_model->getreportDataDaily($user,$date);

        $data = array();
        foreach ($myreport as $patient) {
            $row = array();  
            $row[] = $patient->check_up_id;
            $row[] = $patient->patient_fname;
            $row[] = $patient->patient_lname;
            $row[] = $patient->patient_mname;
            $row[] = $patient->check_up_date;
            $row[] = $patient->clinic_name;
            $row[] = $patient->bill_amt;

            $data[] = $row;
        }
        $output = array(   
            "data" => $data,
        );
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

now here is my data-table that doesn't hide when i check my checkbox above please help me:
https://jsfiddle.net/2j6w9hqt/27/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend manipulating columns visibility by just hiding `th` element.

Instead look into using [Buttons extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) and `colvis` button.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'colvis',
            columns: ':not(:first-child)'
        }
    ]
} );
```

See [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/columns.html) for code and demonstration.

I have also modified default appearance of the column visibility button by adding checkboxes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32701608/3549014) for more details.

Comment: hello sir why it doesnt appear on me.. Here is my code:
function data_table_report(dateselected){
    $("#dataTables-report").dataTable().fnDestroy();

    table =  $('#dataTables-report').DataTable({ 
      "ajax": {
              "url": "<?php echo site_url('patients_report/dataTable_report/')?>"+dateselected,
              "type": "POST",
          },
          responsive: true,
          dom: 'Bfrtip',
          buttons: [ {
                  extend: 'colvis',
                  columns: ':not(:first-child)'
              }]
      });
}

Comment: You need to include CSS/JS files for Buttons extension in addition to DataTables CSS/JS files.

Comment: hello sir, can i add more buttons like buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]

Comment: i mean can i go with two bftrips?